# Unable to start Oracle listener in Docker Oracle on Red Hat

Tags: oracle, docker

I am able to start an Oracle Docker container on my Mac OS, but I cannot start it on Red Hat.  When I run the following on my Mac ...

```
run -it --name oracleofac -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 pdevoasas30l:5000/oracleofac /bin/bash
```

The container starts.  I am able to start oracle by entering ...

```
service oracle-xe start
```

I see the following message

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
```

And I am then able to connect to Oracle and query tables.  Everything is great.  No problems.

However, when I try to load the same Docker image on Red Hat using this command ...

```
sudo docker run -it --name oracleofac -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 -p 49162:8080 localhost:5000/oracleofac /bin/bash
```

the container starts.  But when I try to start oracle using this command ...

```
service oracle-xe start
```

I get the following ...

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

When I type this ...

```
lsnrctl status
```

I see this ...

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-DEC-2015 20:33:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

And when I type this ...

```
lsnrctl start
```

I get the following ...

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-DEC-2015 20:35:02

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/c98964cdfa69/listener/alert/log.xml
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
   Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

Here is the docker file ...

```
FROM wnameless/oracle-xe-11g

COPY initOFAC.sql /app/initOFAC.sql

ENV ORACLE_HOME /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ENV ORACLE_SID XE

RUN sed -i -E "s/HOST = [^)]+/HOST = 0.0.0.0/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora && service oracle-xe start && su -m oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/ as sysdba' @/app/initOFAC.sql"

CMD service oracle-xe start; \
    /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: I see you use https://hub.docker.com/r/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/ maybe a specific user is needed when using Red Hat as I see ` TNS:permission denied` and it seems you are using the user root, as I do not see a `USER xxx` in the dockerfile

Comment: I suppose I am starting it as root on both.  But I don't understand what it works on one OS and not the other.  That brings up another issue that I am not sure is related for not.  In the Mac OS docker container, when I type "sudo su - oracle", it works fine.  However, when I type the same thing in the Red Hat docker container, I get "Unable to cd to '/u01/app/oracle'.

Comment: I suppose you have spotted the problem. Now, why on Red Hat, the user Oracle is not available/fully installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A coworker was able to help me resolve this.  If you run

```
stat /
```

in a docker container on a Mac, you will see this

```
  File: '/'
  Size: 4096      Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096  directory
Device: 20h/32d Inode: 2          Links: 46
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)  Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-12-28 19:43:47.111212548 +0000
Modify: 2015-12-28 19:43:47.281211325 +0000
Change: 2015-12-28 19:43:47.281211325 +0000
Birth: -
```

but if you run it on Red Hat, you will see

```
  File: '/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 131073      Links: 23
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-12-27 22:03:18.043696658 +0000
Modify: 2015-12-27 20:32:44.659975560 +0000
Change: 2015-12-27 20:32:44.659975560 +0000
Birth: -
```

Notice that the access is 755 on the Mac but 750 on Red Hat.  To get around this, I added

```
usermod -G root oracle
```

to the Dockerfile.  The final version of my Dockerfile is now

```
FROM wnameless/oracle-xe-11g

COPY initOFAC.sql /app/initOFAC.sql

ENV ORACLE_HOME /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ENV ORACLE_SID XE

RUN sed -i -E "s/HOST = [^)]+/HOST = 0.0.0.0/g" /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora && service oracle-xe start && su -m oracle -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/ as sysdba' @/app/initOFAC.sql"

CMD usermod -G root oracle; service oracle-xe start; /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

Now this docker image works in both the Mac and Red Hat environments.